# Create specific square shape android

Tags: android, shapes

I've created a button, when it's clicked, it's like the picture below.
[image: the button]

For now, it's an image created with Gimp and `9-patch`. It works, but I want to know if there is a way to create the same image with a **Shape** in XML (only the blue part in the middle). So in the future, I can change for example the color very easily.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :**

I tried something :

```
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/blue1"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

But, of course, it doesn't work. The transparent triangle just show the blue rectangle in the background. Maybe with two triangle and one square, but i'm really weak in android shape system.